# Complex analysis: The taylor series for $\frac{z\cos z}{z-2}$ around $z=0$

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm stucking trying to solve the following problem:

Given a function $f$ given as $f(z)=\frac{z\cdot \cos z}{z-2}$ I am asked to show that the Taylor series for $f$ around $0$ is given as
$$f(z)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_kz^k $$
where $a_0=0$ and
$$a_{2k}=a_{2_k-1}/2 $$
$$ a_{2k+1}=\frac{\left(a_{2k}+\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{(2k)!}\right)}{2}$$

My work so far:

Given
$$f(z)=\frac{z\cdot \cos z}{z-2}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_kz^k$$
it must be the case that
\begin{alignat*}{2}
z\cdot \cos z&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_kz^k(z-2)\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}-2a_kz^k+a_kz^{k+1} \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}-2a_kz^k+a_{k-1}z^{k} \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-2a_k+a_{k-1})z^k \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-a_k+\frac{a_{k-1}}{2})z^k 
\end{alignat*}

From here I'm not sure how to proceed. I know that $z\cdot \cos z=z\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{(2k)!}z^{2k}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{(2k)!}z^{2k+1}$, but I'm not sure how this connects with what I've done so far.

Any tips are appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Observe that the function has a simple pole at $z=2$, so the series will converge for $|z| < 2$, in which region we have

$$\frac{1}{z-2} = -\frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{1-\tfrac{z}{2}}=- \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{2^{n+1}}$$

We also, as you point out, have

$$z \cos(z) = z \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{z^{2n}}{(2n)!} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{z^{2n+1}}{(2n)!}.$$

So the Taylor series will be the product

$$f(z) = \bigg( - \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{2^{n+1}} \bigg) \bigg( \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{z^{2n+1}}{(2n)!} \bigg).$$

Now, from this point, you might be able to find an expression for the $n$-th term in this series using the Cauchy product formula, or you could just write out the first few terms is that is satisfactory.

Comment: Thanks! I haven't really come across the Cauchy product formula in my course before, so I will have to look into that.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:*
$$
\frac{1}{z-2} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{-1}{2^{n+1}}z^n \quad\text{for } |z|<2
$$